# 'It's better/worse as compared with (something)'

Tags: comparative-constructions

My student said the first sentence below, which is a construction I hear fairly often from students. I've searched the data base for an answer, but couldn't find anything similar to what my student found when checking my correction.

Student said: *It's not high quality as compared with beef.*

I suggested: *It's not high quality, compared with beef.* [Honestly, this seems a little strange too.]

He always checks my corrections. I asked him to let me know what he finds out when checking this particular correction. This is what he sent me.

> "It's better/worse as compared with (something)" seems to be a typical
> construction.

This doesn't seem quite right to me. What do you all think?

Comment: "What do you all think?"- About what exactly? About "this" seeming not quite right? What "this"? What the student said? What you suggested? What this mysterious "He" you mention out of the blue who always checks your corrections sent you? Without knowing what you're asking, I'm reluctant to post an answer, so I'll just say I've no issue with what the student said, "as" meaning "like" or "for example," or what you suggested, an absolute phrase equally grammatical, though I prefer "to" over "with." As for "He," his isn't *wrong* grammatically, but the other two are equivalent and his isn't.

Comment: Note that as a native (American) English speaker, "as compared with" sounds like an unidiomatic construction; I would instead simply use "compared to" or "in comparison to". I.e. "It's not as high quality(,) compared to beef".

Comment: The qualification ***compared to/with/against [something else]*** can *optionally* be preceded by  ***as, if,*** or ***when***. In almost all contexts, whether to include any such conjunction (and if so, *which*) is entirely a stylistic choice that has no effect on the meaning.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Got my question answered, and discussed this with my student. All's good.